# Loop through nested array php and prefix value

Tags: php, arrays, json

Reads all the prefix value in an array. If slug value is modules the result would be api/v1/tenants/modules/{id}, in contrast if slug value fetch the result would be api/v1/tenants/fetch/{id}.

```
        "slug" => "api",
        "children" => [
            "prefix" => "v1",
            "slug" => "v1",
            "children" => [
                "prefix" => "tenants",
                "slug" => "tenants",
                "children" => [
                    [
                        "prefix" => "fetch/{id}",
                        "slug" => "fetch",
                    ],
                    [
                        "prefix" => "modules/{id}",
                        "slug" => "modules",
                    ]


                ],
            ],
        ],
```

[image: Array list]

Answer (score 2):

You can use [array_walk_recursive](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) to traverse array recursively,

```
$res = [];
// & so that it keeps data of $res in every loop
array_walk_recursive($arr, function ($item, $key) use (&$res) {
    if ($key == 'prefix') {
        $res[] = $item; // fetching only prefix values recursively
    }

});
// this is your generated url
echo implode("/", $res);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/Btfd5).

**Output**:

```
api/v1/tenants/modules/{id}
```

Answer (score 2):

I use [array-walk-recursive](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) as:

```
function getPrefix($v, $k) { global $ps; if ($k == "prefix") $ps[] = $v; }
array_walk_recursive($arr, 'getPrefix');
```

Now, `$ps` is array of the prefix. Then you can use `implode` to add the `/`

Live example: [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/Kv2bN)

Comment: Not sure of the need to use `global`

Comment: Agreed, @Drakula post is bit better (saw it after I posted mine)